# A dance with an aglorithm's complexity

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion, max, dynamic-programming

I am about to take part in a dance contest and tomorrow is the big day! I know apriori the list with the `n` songs of the contest and their order. After much scouting, I was able to determine the judges and my skills so good that I can accurately predict my result if I dance the i-th song of the list, i.e. `score(i)`.

However, after the i-th song, I need time to rest, namely I cannot dance the next `rest(i)` songs, i.e. songs i + 1, ..., i + rest(i). No other constraint exists for the number of songs I can dance. Give an effective algorithm for computing your ideally maximum total score and its complexity.

---

So I think that recursion should be used, where `max(i) = max(i + 1)` or `max(i) = score(i) + max(i + 1 + rest(i))` and then pick the best out of this two at every step. Can someone help?

Comment: Your idea sounds good, what kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: @BlackBear the attempt I have described doesn't seem like an algorithm. I would like someone to help me expand my idea to an algorithm and if able, provide a hint for the complexity (but I think I will be able to get that out of the algorithm, once we produce it). :)

Comment: Start with the base case. What value do you return?

Comment: Also, `max(i) = max(i + 1)` doesn't make sense. Using python syntax, you're looking for something like `return currentScore + max(recursiveMethod(scores[currentPos+1:]),  recursiveMethod(scores[currentPos+2:]))`. (see list-slicing)

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree! the base case should return 0 I think. Hmm I would suggest you to post an answer with that and expand on it! ;)

Comment: I might be wrong on that. It's been awhile since I did dynamic programming. There's similar logic for the "maximum change from N coins" problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be n songs indexed 0..n-1. Let Opt(i) be the maximum total score given that we're free to dance starting on song i. The recurrence for Opt is

```
Opt(n) = 0
Opt(i) = max(Opt(i+1),
             Score(i) + Opt(i + 1 + Rest(i))) for i = 0..n-1.
```

Intuitively, we either don't dance song i and get the value of the remaining time, or we do, score song i, rest, and get the value of the time after resting.

This recurrence should be evaluated for i descending, with the previously calculated values cached in an array. The running time is O(n).

Comment: Thank you, the dance goes on, for a final step, [check it if you have some time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709017/the-last-algorithmic-dance).

Comment: how can we "solve" this recurrence ? the very first time since i =1 we get : Opt(1) = max(Opt(2),
             Score(1) + Opt(2+ Rest(1)))... , opt(2) and so on are unknown , aren;t they?

Comment: @tonythestark You solve from i = n down to i = 0.

Comment: thank you , i did not notice that the base case was opt(n) instead of opt(0)

Answer (score 2):

Recursion would be,

```
for i: 1 -> n
    DP(n) = max(0,(score(i)+DP(i+r)),DP(i+1))
```

where,

```
r = resting interval
0 is the situation where it is better not to dance at all :)
```

Edit 1: Adding explanation

Base case is participant doesn't dance so the total score will be 0

Otherwise, he either dances or not on a particular song. So the decision boils down to if he should dance on this song or not so that the ultimate score is maximized.

If he decided to dance, he will gain `score(i)` and cannot dance for `rest(i)` so the remaining max possible score will be the value of `score(i) + DP(i + rest(i))`

If he decides not to dance on this song, the score will be `DP(i+1)`.

Because we want to maximize the score, we pick the max of these two values.

Comment: Thank you for the update! The dance goes on, for a final step, [check it if you have some time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709017/the-last-algorithmic-dance).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's also possible to have a bottom down solution :

```
    d[i] = 0 if i = 0
    for all j s.t (i-1-rest(j) >=0 ):
        m = max( score(i) + d[i-1-rest(j)])
    d[i] = max(d[i-1], m)
```

The total running time is O(n^2)