# The last algorithmic dance

Tags: algorithm, recursion, max, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

*[ Previous related question: [A dance with an aglorithm's complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706951/a-dance-with-an-aglorithms-complexity) ]*

The story: I'm about to take part in a dance contest with *n* songs in a specific order. I can't dance to every single song, though, because I need time to prepare before each dance, and time to rest afterward. (Fortunately, the rest time from one dance can overlap with the preparation time for the next.)

I know what score I can get for each song I *do* dance to, and I want to maximize my total score.

So, I have three arrays:

- *score*(*i*) is the score I can get for dancing to song #*i*.
- *prep*(*i*) is the number of songs I have to skip immediately before song #*i*, or else I can't do song #*i*. (For example, if *prep*(4) = 2, then I can't dance to song #4 unless I've skipped both song #2 and song #3.)
- *rest*(*i*) is the number of songs I have to skip immediately after song #*i*, if I did song #*i*. (For example, if *rest*(4) = 2, and I dance to song #4, then I have to skip both song #5 and song #6.)

Neither *prep*(*i*) nor *rest*(*i*) ever exceeds an upper bound, call it *M*.

How can I maximize my score? What's its complexity?

---

My attempt:

Based on the answer already given, take that

```
Opt(i) = max(Opt(i+1),
             Score(i) + Opt(i + 1 + rest(i))) for i = 0..n-1.
```

and build on it, so that we have as a dead time something like:

```
Opt(i + 1 + max(prep(i), rest(i)))
```

but I am worried, since `i` should descend, as mentioned in my linked question. Can anybody help please? That overlapping confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Get the first song that can be danced to assuming he danced to `i` and wanted to wait till prep time of a song
def myPrep(i):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        if j - prep(j) > i:
            return j

for i in range(0,n-1):
    Opt(i) = max(Opt(i+1),
                 (Score(i) + Opt(i + 1 + rest(i))),
                 (Score(i) + Opt(i + 1 + myPrep(i)))
             )
```

In this case, I am thinking of three possibilities:

- Skips current song -> `Opt(i+1)`
- Dances to current song -> `Score(i)` and

  - waits for the resting period of `ith` song or
  - waits for the first song which provides enough prep time -> `myPrep(i)`

I debated with myself if I should include all the possible songs that have enough prep time after `ith` but then thought the `Opt(myPrep(i))` should get the right number and hence we don't need to include all of the songs after `myPrep(i)` in calculation of `ith` song

Comment: I thought of something like that max with the 3 operands, but max isn't used with 2 in general?

Comment: Python max function accepts arbitrarily large input, other languages might differ but if that is the case you can split the `max` like `i = max(x, max(y,z))`

Comment: OK! I was about to use `prep(i)`, instead of `myPrep(i)` in the max function though. Can you explain that a bit? :)

Comment: as mentioned in the comment, `myPrep` returns the first song that can be danced to based on the prep time if he dances to `i`. eg. if `prep = [2,1,1]` and `i = 1`, `myPrep(i)` will return `j = 2` which is second index of `prep`.